# Change Values in lowe triangular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I created the following Matrix:

```
Q = np.asmatrix(np.tril(-1*np.ones(15), -1)[:, ::-1])

print(Q)
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.],
       [ 0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1., -1.]])
```

Then I do some calculations (not relevant for the question) on the matrix so as to change the values currently set to zero.

Ultimately I would like to substitute those -1s by position with 100s, **in the matrix "Q"** (e.g. np.asmatrix(np.tril(-100*np.ones(15), -1)[:, ::-1]) is **not** a solution).

How can I do that?

Comment: if you didn't change the `0` values to `-1` then you just convert using `np.where(Q==-1, -100, Q)` or are you asking how to generate a mask of the lower triangle?

Comment: Use the mask : `mask = np.tri(len(Q),k=-1,dtype=bool)[:,::-1]` ; `Q[mask] = ..`?

Comment: Mask is doing the job! Thanks @Divakar for the answer that I'll accept as you share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create an equivalent `mask` and use it to index into `Q` and assign new values -

```
mask = np.tri(len(Q),k=-1,dtype=bool)[:,::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get index positions of values which equals -1 and then at any time you can access it and assign new values

```
import numpy as np
Q = np.asmatrix(np.tril(-1*np.ones(5), -1)[:, ::-1])

indexes = np.where(Q == -1)

Q[indexes] = -100
print(Q)


[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0. -100.]
 [   0.    0.    0. -100. -100.]
 [   0.    0. -100. -100. -100.]
 [   0. -100. -100. -100. -100.]]
```

Or with MASK

```
Mask = Q==-1
print(Mask)

Q[Mask] = -100
print(Q)

[[False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True]
 [False False False  True  True]
 [False False  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True]]
[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0. -100.]
 [   0.    0.    0. -100. -100.]
 [   0.    0. -100. -100. -100.]
 [   0. -100. -100. -100. -100.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I prefer to use a mask and replace them by position

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli I edited the answer. You have indexes and Mask solution. Its essentially the same

Comment: Thank you for the edit but, since those -1s are changed after lines of code, I prefer to call the mask afterwards by position, without saving a mask at the beginning of the code

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli I dont really know what you mean, since you accepted answer which does basicaly the same as mine. But whatever, I just wanted to complete the answer. Goodluck with your task